# How to launch Jupyter Notebooks with their own folder as the working directory in Visual Studio code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I launch R-based Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code, I want each R notebook to have its working directory set to the directory the file sits in. However, this is not happening (details below).

Various iterations of this question have been asked, but the solutions seem to work only for Python-based Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio code. For those, the solution is simply to update the VS Code settings to set Notebook File Root to `${fileDirname}`:
[image]

That works perfectly fine for my Python code. However, it does not work for R-based Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code on macOS. More specifically, I find that the first R notebook launches with its own folder set as the working directory, as expected. But subsequent R notebooks launch in the same folder as the first R notebook that I launch. (Unlike Python notebooks, which again open just as expected.)

Has anyone gotten R notebooks to open in their expected directory in VS Code (version `1.74.0`)?

Comment: hm. I wonder if it has anything to do with the code in the Jupyter extension that does `if (!isPythonKernelConnection(kernel.kernelConnectionMetadata)) { return; }` in `getWorkingDirectory`, which comes before the code which calls `calculateWorkingDirectory`, which reads `notebookFileRoot`. I'd suggest [raising an issue ticket about this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/new?assignees=octocat&labels=bug&projects=&template=2_bug_form.yml). If you (or anyone else) does, please comment here with a link to it or suggest an edit to the post to add it into the post.